# "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app" on browser at Axios Call Despite 200 response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, package.json

I have seen this similar issue everywhere else however my specific issue is that my create react app but it only ever happens on my Fetch/Axios call (which btw is returning a 200 just fine). If I don't do an axios call my app runs perfectly fine. Everywhere else I've looked also has it on the API call but my API call is still returning a 200.

Did everything under this link right here => https://www.upbeatcode.com/react/solved-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app/
And also made sure to add cors to my backend express.js server (which runs on a different port to my react app)

Would love to get some insight as to why this is happening and how I can resolve it! And would be willing to provide stuff like pseudocode and my package.json files and such when needed.

**react js package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vorboss-airtable",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.10",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the two errors in your console? (Also, the "you need to enable JS" part is irrelevant, that's what would be displayed if JS were disabled)

Comment: @CherryDT Not sure how to check what the red errors in the console are. All my console has is "Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools" and like one of my console.log() debug stuff

Comment: There is an error mounting your app. There is not enough detail to say what’s going wrong.

Comment: @OFRBG I am guessing the error on the mount is happening when I am state changing after my axios call. Here is the specific line of code with the whole context just in case

Comment: @OFRBG https://github.com/MakoMitsuki/vorboss-airtable/blob/9322e2c25064dfdea9b59c334f575ffa48924422/frontend/src/components/Datatable/Datatable.jsx#L68